# ZeosLib (ZeosDBO) + SQLite 3, нужна ли sqlite3.dll?

Tags: база-данных, delphi, sqlite3

Установил ZeosDBO 7.2.1(RC) в Delphi, создал проект использующий базу данных SQLite 3, запустил, всё заработало... И тут вспомнил, что ещё не закинул sqlite3.dll в папку с проектом, а приложение работает, база подключена, читает/записывает... Посмотрел по системным папкам, там такой dll тоже нет. 
Как я понимаю, получается что sqlite3.dll не нужна, т. е. в ZeosLib есть свой собственный (встроенный) драйвер для SQLite? Или, может быть, она у меня просто через какой-то другой драйвер подключается (есть же у других баз совместимость с Interbase, например)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужна. Эта библиотека может лежать и подхватываться не только из системных директорий, но и из любой директории, прописанной в `PATH`. Скорее всего, вы установили какую-то программу, которая прописалась в `PATH` и которая в своей директории содержит `sqlite3.dll`.

Чтобы узнать, от каких конкретно библиотек зависит ваше приложение и где они лежат, есть специальные утилиты. Например, [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

---

Если вам нужна статическая линковка с SQLite3, то могу посоветовать [mORMot](https://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework) фреймворк. Там вместе с сорцами идут прекомпилированные версии SQLite3 `sqlite3.obj` и
`sqlite3fts3.obj`, которые можно подключить статически, включив в проект юнит: `SynSQLite3Static.pas`. Если юнит не подключён, то будет динамическая линковка с `dll`.

Comment: Спасибо, проверил пути из %PATH% - так оно и оказалось, sqlite3.dll есть в папке bin у самой Delphi.